# How to get and display all the data of database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Well i am creating a web app in which i need to display all the rows from the database , the code and database structure is :

```
    ------------------------------------------
    id | product_name | link
    ------------------------------------------
     1 | example_1    | #
     2 | example_2    | #
     3 | example_3    | #

mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `site_product` WHERE `product_cat` = 'home'";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "$row['product_name'];" }
```

so however i get only one result and rest of the rows are not being in output I think of using "forloop" but dnt have any idea to implement it .. please help .

Comment: Could you add your actual code?

Comment: 1. `$result` is missing 2. `echo` missing

Comment: First of all that is not a database structure, it is a table structure. Second that query cannot be being used on that table, because there is no column product_cat. Third, in the code you have posted you never actually run the query!

Please tell us the truth if you want us to help you!

Comment: Why are you asking for help about something without posting the code?

Comment: How many record you see when you run that query in phpmyadmin? If you get all records please post your actual code. We can't find what is wrong if you post only pieces of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you are asking for this:

```
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row AS $field)
        echo "<td>$field</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

On this code you wrote, the `}` is inside the String, so the loop is not closed.

It's the only problem I see in these part of the code.

Comment: Just because the full code wasn't posted ;)

Comment: Oh i made it by mistake

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `mysql_query` first before fetching data : your code corrected

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `site_product` WHERE `product_cat` = 'home'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['product_name']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `$result` defined??? You copied wrong.
Use this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `site_product` WHERE `product_cat` = 'home'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['product_name']; }
```

Comment: echo "$row['product_name'];" should be echo $row['product_name]; or echo "{row['product_name']}";